# azure detatch disk from deleted virtual machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, disk

I had a virtual machine on Azure which stopped responding, so I deleted it with the hopes of recreating it using the same vhd. However after deleting the virtual machine, the disks is somehow still connected to the VM, and thus I can't use the vhd to recreate the VM. I've already tried using Windows Powershell ISE to import the publishsettings file and then using the Remove-AzureDisk command, but the result is `HTTP Status Code: BadRequest - HTTP Error Message: A disk with name *diskname* is currently in use by virtual machine *VMName* running within hosted service *dnsname*, deployment *deploymentname*.`

Any ideas how to fix this? I would rather not have to delete the vhd, since it is a pain to reupload it.

Comment: This sounds like a question for ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this many times.  The hold on the Disk should release in 15 minutes or so.  I've never seen it last more than that.

If all else fails, you could try to break the lease on the BLOB and re-create a DISK using it.  I have a took for that here:  http://www.biztalkgurus.com/windows_azure/m/windows_azure/37137.aspx

Comment: Well, the hold released sometime during the night, but before I went to bed, it had been held for more than four hours. I have no idea why it didn't release immediately though. I've seen this issue unanswered at the msdn forums, so hopefully other people will find your answer if they experience the same thing. Thanks!